# How to use IPFS without providing online access for specific folders and files?

Tags: caching, offline, ipfs

IPFS provides useful caching mechanism. **My goal** is to use IPFS caching mechanism without providing an online access.

Even I do not share the `ipfs-hash` of the file with other users, I want to disable probability for other users to access/pull that file I stored on my local IPFS directory, somehow if they find out the `ipfs-hash` of the file/folder.

**=>** If I don't run `ipfs daemon` would it be a solution? If yes, the problem is for some files I may need to use `ipfs daemon` to share them with other users or I also may need to pull files from other nodes. The problem rises that when I start running ipfs daemon this will enable access to all the files that is stored on the local ipfs folder.

**[Q]** So basically I want to use `IPFS` as a offline caching tool and do not provide outside access for some specific folders that I store in IPFS. Even ipfs daemon was running, could I disable online access for specific files/folders that I decide?

*For example,* I have multiple folders and I want to store them under local IPFS folder, where who ever has their `ipfs-hash` will not be get able to pull those files. Even ipfs daemon is running could I force those folders that is stored in local IPFS folder to have no outside access? and provide online access for some other folders.

---

As a solution, on my machine could I run two different IPFS processes having different local repository. First one is open to outside and can pull from other nodes etc. (running `ipfs daemon`); but other does not have any access to outside and no-one can access to its files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the offline mode mentioned by Victor Bjelkholm, you can look into setting up a private swarm. For instructions, see https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks

That way you have a node that can be connected to other nodes of yours with the same swarm key, it is *absolutely impossible* for this node to intentionally or accidentally connect to the public IPFS network.

Answer (score 6):

You can run the daemon in offline-mode meaning it won't make any outside connections. You can do this by running `ipfs daemon --offline` and confirming that there is no swarm addresses outputted after starting the daemon.

Comment: I want to use IPFS's caching mechanism to store files and folders for a purpose of a project I am working on. By default I want to store all the files as offline mode. Later, if it is required I want to give access to some specific files distributed to different nodes, while keeping others offline mode. Your answer `ipfs daemon --offline` lets all the files remain in offline mode no matter what. How could I allow some specific files able to be distributed on different nodes? Is it possible?